# Lisp Coin Toss Heads sequence

Tags: tree, count, lisp

In Lisp, I have to create a program that does the following (please visit link):

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/103/10328.html

I have code to create the tree

```
(defun head-tail (n  &optional (total 0))
  (if (< total n)
      (list(cons 'H (head-tail n (1+ total)))
             (cons 'T (head-tail n (1+ total))))
    nil))
```

and then code to check the sequence of H = heads

```
(defun head-search2 (tree n &optional (total 0) (check 0))
  (cond ((null tree)
         check)
        ((listp (first tree))
         (+ (head-search2 (first tree) n total)
            (head-search2 (rest tree) n total check)))
        ((and (eq (first tree) 'H)
              (>= (1+ total) n))
         (head-search2 (rest tree) n (1+ total) 1))
        ((and (eq (first tree) 'H)
              (< (1+ total) n))
         (head-search2 (rest tree) n (1+ total) check))
        ((eq (first tree) 'T)
         (head-search2 (rest tree) n 0 check ))))
```

and a last function to combine those two

```
(defun head-check (m n)
  (head-search2(head-tail m) n))
```

The code is not working with large numbers of trees, any help would be great!

Comment: What does "is not working with large numbers of trees" mean?

Comment: like when i use it for a tree of 3 looking for sequences of 2 it has a correct result but for a tree = 4 and sequence = 2 doesnt work it outputs 7 when it should output 8 and tree = 6 n = 2 gives 31 instread of 43. @zmccord

Comment: The web page you point to does not make something clear. You are not actually performing a coin toss experiment (like with a pseudo-random number generator). You're processing all `(expt 2 n)` possible combinations of heads and tails, and looking for sequences of H. This is purely a combinatorial problem, similar to: wow many N bit binary numbers from 0 to 2^N contain a consecutive sequence of at least K  zero bits.   Right?

Comment: i am creating a tree of all the possible sequences. and then read that to see how many Hs appear in a row. yes i am not performing a coin toss why is that a problem ? 
the link is the actuall problem. i dont understand what are you saying .. this is the problem dont try to change it.. @Kaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. In the function `head-search2`, second clause of `cond`, first recursive call to `head-search2` fails to propagate the `check` down.
2. Same clause, second recursive call gets `(rest tree)` as first parameter, which results in an extra layer of list; it should be `(second tree)` instead.

That said, you traverse the tree twice: first when constructing, and then counting it.  With a little bit more careful thinking, you can save a lot of work traversing it just once, without constructing it explicitly:

```
(defun count-n-runs (m n &optional (k n))
  "Count all possible binary sequences with n consecutive 1s."
  (cond ((= 0 n) (expt 2 m))
        ((= 0 m) 0)
        ((+ (count-n-runs (1- m) k k)
            (count-n-runs (1- m) (1- n) k)))))
```

Rewriting this further for dynamic programming is left as an exercise for the reader.  ;)